# about mongodb update last data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

now i hava some data like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6fe7518fd89a4d33983ca0"),
    "id" : "475753578774925312",
    "inTime" : ISODate("2018-01-30T03:32:32.000Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6fe7558fd89a4d33983ca3"),
    "id" : "475753578774925312",
    "inTime" : ISODate("2018-01-30T03:32:36.000Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6fe7598fd89a4d33983ca5"),
    "id" : "475753578774925312",
    "inTime" : ISODate("2018-01-30T03:32:40.000Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6fe75d8fd89a4d33983ca8"),
    "id" : "475753578774925312",
    "inTime" : ISODate("2018-01-30T03:32:44.000Z")
}
```

and i want to update the latest intime data setting a new column name outtime when the column is not exists,if the new column has already existed ,i want this update to change to a new insert,how can I do?

first update:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6fe7518fd89a4d33983ca0"),
    "id" : "475753578774925312",
    "inTime" : ISODate("2018-01-30T03:32:32.000Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6fe7558fd89a4d33983ca3"),
    "id" : "475753578774925312",
    "inTime" : ISODate("2018-01-30T03:32:36.000Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6fe7598fd89a4d33983ca5"),
    "id" : "475753578774925312",
    "inTime" : ISODate("2018-01-30T03:32:40.000Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6fe75d8fd89a4d33983ca8"),
    "id" : "475753578774925312",
    "outTime" : ISODate("2018-01-30T03:32:44.000Z"),
    "inTime" : ISODate("2018-01-30T03:32:44.000Z")
}
```

second update:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6fe7518fd89a4d33983ca0"),
    "id" : "475753578774925312",
    "inTime" : ISODate("2018-01-30T03:32:32.000Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6fe7558fd89a4d33983ca3"),
    "id" : "475753578774925312",
    "inTime" : ISODate("2018-01-30T03:32:36.000Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6fe7598fd89a4d33983ca5"),
    "id" : "475753578774925312",
    "inTime" : ISODate("2018-01-30T03:32:40.000Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6fe75d8fd89a4d33983ca8"),
    "id" : "475753578774925312",
    "outTime" : ISODate("2018-01-30T03:32:44.000Z"),
    "inTime" : ISODate("2018-01-30T03:32:44.000Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6fe75d8fd89a4d33983ca8"),
    "id" : "475753578774925312",
    "outTime" : ISODate("2018-01-30T03:32:44.000Z")
}
```

if these operations exist concurrency，how can i avoid repeat update

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Share the expected output in JSON

Answer (score 0):

- This is not a one step problem to approach the result.
- The solution would be like this:-
- Fetch the latest record from DB as 
  **db.collection_name.find().sort({"inTime":-1}).limit(1)**
- If this query returns any document with column name as "outTime" then modify the value and update record.
- Else insert a new row.

Comment: if these operations exist concurrency，how can i avoid repeat update

Comment: Create synchronised method and place your logic inside it.